# ConvexHull in Graphics - Mathematica

Tags: graphics, wolfram-mathematica, convex-hull

Trying to plot a ConvexHull Using PlanarGraphPlot from the ComputationalGeometry package, it does not work when used in graphics.

Any Idea on how to plot the ConvexHull using Graphics ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"]
pts = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {60, 2}];

Graphics[
 {
  Point@pts,
  FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Red],
  Polygon@pts[[ConvexHull[pts]]]
  }
 ]
```

or

```
cpts = pts[[ConvexHull[pts]]];
AppendTo[cpts, cpts[[1]]];

Graphics[
 {
  Point@pts,
  Red,
  Line@cpts
  }
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Well, Actually you had that figured out using Faceform[white]. Is there another way as I might have to show some graphics under the ConvexHull

Comment: @500 If you don't want to see the points there's nothing easier than leaving out the line that draws them and that I included for illustrative purposes (`Point@pts`). I'm not sure if I understand you here. I don't understand your question about `Faceform[white]` either. I use `Faceform[]` which causes the polygon to be transparent.

Comment: Thank You. Sorry for the confusion, I got it figured out now !

Answer (score 5):

Not sure exactly what is wanted. Maybe the code below will get you started.

```
 pts = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {20, 2}]
(*
Out[1]= {{1.7178, -1.11179}, {-7.10708, -8.1637},
 {8.74461, -2.42551}, {6.64129, -2.87008}, {9.9008, 6.47825},
 {8.27081, 9.94116}, {9.97325, 7.61094}, {-2.7876, 9.70449},
 {-3.69357, 0.0253506}, {-0.503817, -1.98649}, {6.3056, -1.16892},
 {-4.69983, -1.93242}, {-6.09983, 7.49229}, {8.08545, 6.67951},
 {-6.91195, 8.34752}, {-2.63136, 6.0506}, {-0.130006, 2.10929},
 {1.64401, 3.32165}, {0.611335, -8.11364}, {-2.03548, -9.37277}}
*)
With[{hull = pts[[Graphics`Mesh`ConvexHull[pts]]]}, 
  Graphics[Line[Append[hull, First[hull]]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Ouch. I forgot how to attach a gif.

Comment: You're probably kidding but just in case you're not: press the little graphics button above the edit window to provide a link or path. I usually export to PNG, because it has better color resolution than GIF, if I'mnot mistaken.

Comment: Voting to delete. No gif, no answer.

Comment: Wasn't kidding. I had done it correctly, actually, but no image showeed up. Worked for a jpeg but not a gif?!

Comment: That is odd; I typically use GIF for StackOverflow.

Comment: @Daniel @Mr.Wiz I don't think it was Gif vs. JPG. The image server is unreachable sometimes. I've seen that happening before.

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries Ah. That is probably what happened. Thanks for explaining.