# Plot DelaunayTriangulation in Mathematica

Tags: graphics, geometry, wolfram-mathematica

Considering the following example ([from Sjoerd Solution on plotting a ConvexHull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270778/convexhull-in-graphics-mathematica))

```
Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"]
pts = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {60, 2}];
dtpts=DelaunayTriangulation[pts]
```

I would now like to plot the DelaunayTriangulation for a set of point but can`t figure out the Plot syntax using Graphics.

Thoughts ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Graphics[
  GraphicsComplex[
    pts, 
    {
      Function[{startPt, finishPts},Line[{startPt, #}] & /@ finishPts] @@@ dtpts, 
      Red, Point@Range[Length@pts]
    }
   ]
  ]
```

[image]

And if you need real polygons:

```
Graphics[
 GraphicsComplex[
  pts, 
  {EdgeForm[Black], 
   Function[{startPt, finishPts}, 
      {FaceForm[RGBColor[RandomReal[], RandomReal[], RandomReal[]]], 
        Polygon[{startPt, ##}]} & @@@ 
          Transpose[{Drop[finishPts, 1], 
                     Drop[RotateRight@finishPts, 1]
                    }
          ]
         ] @@@ dtpts, 
   Red, Point@Range[Length@pts]
  }
 ]
]
```

[image]

Comment: @Sjoerd, thank you again ! I edited my question to describe dtpts.

Comment: New interpretation of the output. This is better

Comment: Well, it still isn't perfect. The way they are generated, all polygons appear multiple times in the triangulation results. But that's a question of sorting and using Union.

Comment: @Sjoerd, would you know how to count the number of edges ?

Comment: @500 brett has defined an edges function. You could use that, sort the edge points, delete duplicates, count. Easy.

Comment: I think the number of edges should be `Total[Length/@ dtpts[[All,2]]]/2`.

Answer (score 4):

Method one, using polygons like Sjoerd, but without the problem caused by points on the convex hull:

```
Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], 
  Polygon[pts[[#]] & /@ 
    DeleteCases[dtpts, {i_, _} /; MemberQ[ConvexHull[pts], i]][[All, 
      2]]], Red, Point[pts]}]
```

Method two, using lines connecting the adjacent points:

```
edges[pts_, {a_, l_List}] := {pts[[a]], #} & /@ pts[[l]]
Graphics[{Line[edges[pts, #]] & /@ dtpts, Red, Point[pts]}]
```

Both of these methods result in duplicated primitives (three polygons or two lines, from using each point as a starting point.)

We can modify the data slightly and use built in visualization functions:

```
Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], 
  Cases[Normal[
    ListDensityPlot[{##, 0.} & @@@ pts, Mesh -> All]], _Polygon, 
   Infinity], Red, Point[pts]}, ImageSize -> 175]
```

[image]

Comment: I already changed my solution 15 minutes ago. I have a polygon solution ready for an update too...

Answer (score 1):

I like Sjoerd's use of `GraphicsComplex`, but I don't see the need for the baroque code in the middle.

This appears to work just fine:

```
Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"]
pts = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {60, 2}];
dtpts = DelaunayTriangulation[pts];
```

---

### Lines

```
Graphics[GraphicsComplex[
  pts,
  {Line /@ Thread /@ dtpts, Red, Point@Range@Length@pts}
]]
```

[image]

---

### Polygons

```
Graphics[GraphicsComplex[
  pts,
  {
    EdgeForm[Black],
    ( {FaceForm[RGBColor @@ RandomReal[1, 3]], Polygon@#} & /@ 
      Append @@@ Thread@{Partition[#2, 2, 1], #} & ) @@@ dtpts,
    Red,
    Point@Range[Length@pts]
  }
]]
```

[image]